# Python regular expression for commit messages

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to construct a regular expression for commit messages of the following format...

`<message> Issue: <issue> [Reviewer: <reviewer>]`

As you can see, the reviewer section is optional - not every commit has to be reviewed. However, if the reviewer LABEL has been provided - the actual reviewer person is required.

[Here is my regular expression so far](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(.%2B%3F)Issue(%3F%3A%5B-%3A%5Cs%5D*)(.%2B%3F)(%3F%3AReviewer(%3F%3A%5B-%3A%5Cs%5D*)(.%2B%3F))%3F%24&test_string=Updated%20the%20code.%20Issue%3A%20FOO-123.%20Reviewer%3A%20Obama&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0))

The regex is set up so it captures the `message`, `issue`, and `reviewer`.
The problem is, if you don't specify a reviewer - the regex still matches. How can I make it require an actual reviewer rather than just the label "Reviewer"?

EDIT:

### Valid examples...

`Updated code. Issue: FOO-123.`

`Updated tests. Issue: BAR-123. Reviewer: Tim`

### Invalid example...

`Updated readme. Issue: AAA-123. Reviewer:`

Comment: If you need to make `Reviewer` part obligatory, remove the last `?`

Comment: If the text doesn't say who the reviewer is, the regex just assumes `Reviewer` is part of the issue identifier.

Comment: @user2357112 Yeah I understand that problem - I need a solution.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't need to make the `Reviewer` part obligatory.

Comment: Is the issue identifier format actually strict enough that it *can't* end in `Reviewer`? Could the issue identifier ever be something like "Regex Produces Incorrect Match For Line Ending In Reviewer" or something like that, which ends in "Reviewer"?

Comment: @user2357112 Nah I think thats just overkill. I'll trust the devs not to end their message in issue or their issue in reviewer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to be more specific in matching what qualifies as an issue. If anything can qualify as an issue then "FOO-123. Reviewer:" is a valid issue name. If you know your issue will look like "FOO-123" then you can restrict matches to [A-Z]+-[0-9]+
Here is an [example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5E(.%2B%3F)Issue%3A%20(%5BA-Z%5D%2B)-(%5B0-9%5D%2B)%5C.((%20Reviewer%3A%20%5B-%3A%5Cs%5D*)(.%2B%3F))%3F%24&test_string=Updated%20the%20code.%20Issue%3A%20FOO-123.%20Reviewer%3A%20O&ignorecase=1&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0).

Comment: I think I addressed this in the comments. I am trusting devs not to use the Issue and Reviewer words in their messages. That's not my main concern. Also, your regex still matches if the input is `Updated the code. Issue: FOO-123. Reviewer: ` which is invalid.

Comment: Updated the regex. Was accepting a space as a valid Reviewer. My point was not that devs might put Reviewer in their issue name, but that if you accept all strings as issues than it will match. You have to restrict what qualifies as an issue in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Can you work with something like:

```
^(.*?)\sIssue:\s(.*?)\sReviewer:\s(.*?)$
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eDArYH/1)

Comment: It doesn't work when I take out the reviewer section.

Comment: ***The problem is, if you don't specify a reviewer - the regex still matches*** - Can you please update your question with some examples? it will be clearer.